# Unable to assign value to variable on line other than declaration of variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, class-library

I am new to C# learning and this is my first question on stack-overflow. I am getting error code CS0103 (name "exampleInt" does not exist in current context) as I try to initialize variable. But if I initialize it on same line (previous line) where I declare it, no error shows up.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        
        // No error shows up here for
        // private int exampleIn=77;

        private int exampleInt; 

        // error on following line
        exampleInt=77;

    }
}
```

Comment: Put the last line of code inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

A class encapsulates the behaviour of your object and it contains constructors, methods, properties, constants, instance variable etc.

Now you have declared an instance variable `private int exampleInt;`

The `exampleInt` can be used inside you class `ClassLibrary1` only - but it needs to be encapsulated either in a method or in the constructor , in a property etc.

By referencing it outside a context - the instance has no meaning - hence the error.

Try to do the following:

```
public void SetMyExample()
{
  exampleInt=77;
}
```

Now when you create an object of type `ClassLibrary1`

```
ClassLibrary1 myClass = new ClassLibrary1();
```

and call `myClass.SetMyExample();` `exampleInt` will be set to 77

Since `exampleInt` is `private` can only be accessed within the class `ClassLibrary1` scope you might want to be able to get its value.

You could use:

```
public int GetMyExample()
{
  return exampleInt;
}
```

you can call the method `var myExample = myClass.GetMyExample();`